# Brace expansion with a Bash variable - {0..$foo}

Tags: bash, brace-expansion

```
WEEKS_TO_SAVE=4
mkdir -p weekly.{0..$WEEKS_TO_SAVE}
```

gives me a folder called weekly.{0..4}

Is there a secret to curly brace expansion while creating folders I'm missing?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`bash` does `brace expansion` before `variable expansion`, so you get `weekly.{0..4}`.
Because the result is predictable and safe(**Don't trust user input**), you can use `eval` in your case:

```
$ WEEKS_TO_SAVE=4
$ eval "mkdir -p weekly.{0..$((WEEKS_TO_SAVE))}"
```

**note**:

1. `eval` is evil
2. use `eval` carefully

Here, `$((..))` is used to force the variable to be evaluated as an integer expression.

Comment: I almost downvotes this because of the use of eval. I would consider a C-sytle for loop the "proper" way, but this is the only way to accomplish it while running mkdir only once.

Comment: What's wrong with eval? Everything you do in bash is "dangerous", eval doesn't make things worse.

Comment: @kev I googled 'eval is evil' and found: _worthy scenarios make up a tiny percentage of the actual usage of eval.  In the majority of cases, eval is used like a sledgehammer swatting a fly -- it gets the job done, but with too much power.  It's slow, it's unwieldy, and tends to magnify the damage when you make a mistake._ So is this a worthy case or are the other options listed here better?

Comment: That quote is talking about JScript (i.e. MS JavaScript). It's out of context here.

Comment: @user123444555621, no, not everything you do in bash is dangerous. Parameter expansion happens **after** parsing for quotes, command substitution, redirection, etc; thus, data from expanding a parameter can't invoke new subcommands by including `$(rm -rf /)` or write to a file by including `>/etc/passwd`... **unless** you use `eval`, in which case that data is parsed as code.

Comment: @Grault, it's certainly accurate even here; see above, and also BashFAQ #48 (http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy  From a practical point of view, 95%+ of the bash scripts that I see in real production environments are dangerous (not to mention buggy, ugly, not readable, ...). Trying to fight this by disallowing 'eval', is like fighting the ocean with a sand castle. The only real answer I've seen is to flip to programming environment that support more stricter grammar, error control.

Comment: I get that `$((..))` would force it do arithmetic expansion, but why do we have to use `$((WEEKS_TO_SAVE))` instead of simple `$WEEKS_TO_SAVE`, what could `$WEEKS_TO_SAVE` potentially damage

Answer (score 11):

Curly braces don't support variables in BASH, you can do this:

```
 for (( c=0; c<=WEEKS_TO_SAVE; c++ ))
 do
    mkdir -p weekly.${c}
 done
```

Answer (score 10):

Another way of doing it without eval and calling mkdir only once:

```
WEEKS_TO_SAVE=4
mkdir -p $(seq -f "weekly.%.0f" 0 $WEEKS_TO_SAVE)
```

Comment: Boo, hiss; Doesn't work if you have whitespace or other characters in IFS in your format string.

Answer (score 2):

[Brace expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Brace-Expansion) does not support it. You will have to do it using a [loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9337541/495041).

> Brace expansion is performed before any other expansions, and any
>   characters special to other expansions are preserved in the result. It
>   is strictly textual. Bash does not apply any syntactic interpretation
>   to the context of the expansion or the text between the braces. To
>   avoid conflicts with parameter expansion, the string ‘${’ is not
>   considered eligible for brace expansion

.

Answer (score 1):

If you happen to have `zsh` installed on your box, your code as written *will* work with Z-shell if you use `#!/bin/zsh` as your interpreter:

#### Example

```
$ WEEKS_TO_SAVE=4
$ echo {0..$WEEKS_TO_SAVE}
0 1 2 3 4
```