# Issue with Expression in For Loop - Bash

Tags: bash, for-loop, expression, eval

I am trying to loop through a list of servers and rather than manually enter each one in a text file, I wanted to use an expression.

Example:

```
[user@server001 ~]$ for i in server{001..010} ; do echo $i ; done
server001
server002
server003
server004
server005
server006
server007
server008
server009
server010
```

That Produces the desired result. However when I put server{001..010} into a .txt file and try to do the same thing, it doesn't work:

```
[user@server001 ~]$ cat server_test2.txt
server{001..010}
[user@server001 ~]$ for i in `cat server_test2.txt` ; do echo $i ; done
server{001..010}
```

As you can see it doesn't actually handle the expression the way I'd like it to.

Any ideas how I can extrapolate from a txt file with multiple lines of servers using the expression method? {001..010}

Comment: Order of operations. The output from a command substitution is not brace expanded.

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9337489/bash-curly-brace-expansion-with-variable-for-mkdir

Comment: The order of expansions is listed here: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Expansions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use eval; like this:

```
list=$(cat server_test2.txt)
CMD="for i in $list ; do echo \$i; done"
eval $CMD
```

Comment: That worked great, thanks! I'll have to read up on eval to understand why ;)

Comment: `man eval` should help you on your way: it "evaluates" the string as a command. As noted in related questions; it is a "dangerous" command though