# Brace expansion not working when used with variables

Tags: regex, shell, unix

If I run this command in a shell with static values (i.e., `27..97`), it works fine and gives the desired output

```
>ls -d $WORKDIR/batch/somefilename_{27..97}.* 2>/dev/null
somefilename_27.sometxt
somefilename_28.sometxt
somefilename_29.sometxt
..
somefilename_97.sometxt
```

But if I want to include variables or pass arguments to regular expression then I get the error

```
ls: cannot access /home/work/batch/somefilename_{27..96}.*: No such file or directory
```

But that’s not true because the file is present but somehow with variables the regex is not working.

```
>segStart="27"
>segEnd="96"
>myvar="$segStart..$segEnd"
>echo $segStart
27
>echo $segEnd
96
>echo $myvar
27..96

ls -d $WORKDIR/batch/somefilename_{$myvar}.*
"ls: cannot access /home/work/batch/somefilename_{27..96}.*: No such file or directory"
>array=($(ls -d $WORKDIR/batch/somefilename_$myvar.* 2>/dev/null))
>len=${#array[*]}
>echo $len
0
```

Note: I am trying to store in an array the directory names where the name is between two integers: e.g., there are 1-100 directories available with name `file_1.some`, `file_2.some`, `file_3.some`, … `file_100.some`.

If a user wants to get directories from 47 till 97, then I want to read those numbers, store them, and pass them in above `ls` command.

If you have any other alternative that will also help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Brace expansion with a Bash variable - {0..$foo}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9337489/brace-expansion-with-a-bash-variable-0-foo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Brace expansion and globbing are very different from regular expressions
2. Brace expansions happen at defined places in the shell grammar (not in quotes or after parameter expansion; see `man bash`)
3. Please don’t use `ls` to get a list of files in an array: the following should work just fine

```
arr=(path{1..10}*)
```

Or, `arr=(path*)` and then you can filter by testing with `[[` the ones you want to get rid of.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply Ben, I tried using your above command "arr=(path{1..10}*)" its not working, it is giving me only one file name and not an array. 

Also I shall read the man in meantime, thanks again :)

Comment: Do note that `$arr` is not the same as `${arr[@]}`

Comment: yes thank you, the arr=(path{1..10}*) with ${arr[@]} works but even though the 97-100 file is not available then also it stores those filenames in the array which is not correct. Only those file which is available that should only be captured. Maybe I have to build some code around it so that it checks 

Again if we pass variables in arr=(path{1..10}*) then it is still not working, same as ls.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `seq` command to accomplish this:

```
ls -d $WORKDIR/batch/somefilename_$(seq $segStart $segEnd).*
```

If you start from 1 for example and want to have it with leading zero (01) you can use formated output of `seq` like this:

```
seq -f "%02.0f" $segStart $segEnd"
```

Comment: @oguzismail, did not know it is duplicate :)

Comment: No problem. You know now