# Beginner: how can i use a $variable inside curly braces?

Tags: bash

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to use a $var inside curly braces {}..

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "How many files must there be built?" numb
for n in {1..$numb}
do
    echo "Building file $n"
    touch file$n.txt
done
```

This would result in:

```
How many files must there be built?8
Building file {1..8}
```

I've tried enclosing the $numb inside backticks or double quotes but to no avail..

Answer (score 0):

You could use this syntax for your loop:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "How many files must there be built?" numb
for ((i=1; i<=$numb; i++)); do
    echo "Building file $i"
    touch file$i.txt
done
```

It's less fancy, but it works.

Comment: You don't need the `$` sign inside the math `(())` operator.

Comment: In [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), see the section _Answer Well-Asked Questions_, and therein the bullet point regarding questions that "have been asked and answered many times before"

Comment: Indeed, the question was already asked before and had 5 upvoted answers already, including the solution you mention (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9337541/10669875). It's better to avoid duplicate answers. The other question contains all solutions at one place, which is more convenient than having to browse multiple questions to find the best answer.

Comment: Less fancy, *and* better performing. The brace expansion is fully expanded before the loop begins; the C-style loop only sets `i` on demand, so there's a drastic difference between the two when `numb` is large.