# Bash script option to control the number of iterations

Tags: bash, arguments

I would like to run `scan.sh` script and pass all options to the executable `vimba`, e.g. `./vimba -b 4 -t 0.1 -s 3`. Option `b` is ignored by `vimba` and indicates how many times `vimba` is called in a loop by `scan.sh`.

So far, I have:

```
while getopts ":b" option; do
  case $option in
    b) n="$OPTARG";;
    *) ;;
  esac
done

echo "$n"

for i in {1..$n}
do
  ./vimba $*
done
```

The problem is that variable `n` is not getting the value from option `b`:

```
paul@desktop:~/st-cpp/vimba/build$ bash scan.sh -b 4 -s 3 -t 0.2

t=0.2 s=3
```

How to make option `b` value to control the number of iterations? My bash knowledge is near zero. Its syntax looks pretty horrid.

---

I looked at [Brace expansion with a Bash variable - {0..$foo}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9337489/brace-expansion-with-a-bash-variable-0-foo) and edited my script:

```
while getopts ":b" option; do
  case $option in
    b) n="$OPTARG";;
    *) ;;
  esac
done

echo "$n"

for i in {1..$((n))}
do
  ./vimba $*
done
```

but it still doesn't work. Why `echo "$n"` is producing an empty line?

---

I missed a colon. This works:

```
while getopts ":b:" option; do
  case $option in
    b) n="$OPTARG";;
    *) ;;
  esac
done

echo "$n"

for ((i=1; i<=$n; i++))
do
  ./vimba $*
done
```

but I still don't know why the original loop `for i in {1..$((n))}` doesn't work.

Comment: Use an arithmetic loop like `for ((i=1; i<=n; i++)); do ...`. Or write this in a language you know.

Comment: @oguzismail Yes, I found the c loop option and it works. What is the problem with `for i in {1..$((n))}`?

Comment: Integer sequence expansions (`{x..y}`) are performed before arithmetic expansions (`$((expr))`); bash doesn't expand `{1..$((n))}` because the right hand side is not an integer. Keep in mind that `{1..3}` is syntactic sugar for `1 2 3`; which means the sequence is expanded, stored in an array, and looped over. C loops are preferable as they don't involve such costly operations.

Comment: [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) identifies several problems with the code, including [SC2051 - Bash doesn't support variables in brace range expansions](https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC2051).  The report that it produces includes links to more information about the problems and how to fix them.  It's a good idea to run [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) on all new and modified shell code.

Comment: Do a `for i in $(seq $n)` instead.

Comment: There's no reason to run `seq` over the more efficient C-style for loop when using bash.

Comment: @tjm3772 There is a style reason: declarative vs. imperative. For my use case, the inefficiency is not noticeable.

Comment: Not really sure why that matters, but they're effectively both imperative and to the extent that `seq` might technically be declarative it is declarative for the exact reason that many people recommend avoiding external programs and using shell builtins instead whenever possible - the behavior of your program will end up depending on what `seq` you have installed and your PATH,  rather than being consistent and predictable within the targeted shell.